# GemFire model which can insert data to GemFire via microservice

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to find implementation of GemFire and I am in search of model which can insert data to GemFire as well.  I am getting PDX serialization error using `CacheWriter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of example in both the Pivotal GemFire and Spring space.

As you may know, Pivotal GemFire is based on the open source [Apache Geode](http://geode.apache.org/), which has a few [How-To articles](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/How-to+articles) on the Wiki.  There is an article on [*Geode In 5 Minutes*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutesGeodein5minutes) that lead you to a few other places.

With *Spring Data GemFire*, there are plenty of examples, starting with the [*Spring GemFire Examples* GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples).

I also have several other examples in my own GitHub account, such as...

1. The [*Contacts Application*](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application) Reference Implementation (RI).  This is the most current, up-to-date set of examples since I use these as a single source of truth for conference talks as well as to showcase the latest developments in GemFire with *Spring*.
2. I also have an entire GitHub Repository ([spring-gemfire-tests](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache)) dedicated to reproducing/understanding customer issues, building prototypes or proof-of-concepts, and so on.
3. Last, but certainly not least, you can review the [SDG test suite](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire), which has many of tests that can be used as examples for putting/getting data to/from GemFire using *Spring* along with configuring PDX.  #2 above is also a good resource for this as well.

If you are looking for something in particular, pertaining to your UC, let use know what you UC is and perhaps we/I can direct you better.

Hope this helps!

-John